# The Vatican Relic Heist

Tags: knowledge, cipher

Deep within the catacombs of Rome, we discovered a secret entrance into the catacombs beneath Vatican City. Upon further exploration, we discovered a great vault. On the massive door of the vault is depicted a man worshiping an angel. Additionally, on the door is a keypad prompting for a five digit pass-code.

Given the nature of the vault, we suspect it to contain [first-class relics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relic#Christianity) of the Roman Catholic Church. A trusted informant serving in the Papal Apartments has delivered a message to us which he says contains the five digit code to get into the vault. It is as follows:

> 2504 2491 3588 191 2532 991 3778 2532 3753 191 2532 4098 4352 1715 3588 4228 3588 32 3588 1166 1473 3778

Can you decipher the message to find the code and open the vault?

What do we find inside the vault?

Hint:

> The body of the riddle contains the answer to the second question, speculation is unnecessary.

Comment: 3588 is very popular.

Comment: rot13(Vg frrzf gung lbh unir hfrq Yrkvba Ovoyr Terrx Genafyngvba.)

Answer (score 4):

**Partial Answer**

> The message in encrypted by **Strong's Greek Dictionary**(https://greeklexicon.org/)

---

Now coming to message.

> `I ABCD, hear and see this and when heard and fall down and kneel before the foot of angels, those showed me this.`

---

> Here ABCD can be **Joannes**(90%), John: the Baptist, John: the Apostle, John Mark.

---

> Thanks to @Stiv and @JS1 
>  The text is taken from Revelation 22:8.(https://biblehub.com/revelation/22-8.htm). Reading the whole chapter 22 reveals something about the scroll and it could be a first-class relic as it is directly related to Jesus.

---

The Code(thanks to @JS1),

> ***66228*** Reason- Revelation is the 66th book of Bible. And the text is taken from Revelation 22 verse 8.

---

What will we find inside the vault?,

> not quite sure yet. I guess it's some scroll(again thanks to @JS1).

Comment: (A) How did you think of trying this?? Impressive. B) These words bear a striking resemblance to rot13(Eriryngvba puncgre 22 irefr 8) - maybe head there next for further inspiration...?

Comment: Rot13(Vs guvf vf eriryngvbaf 22:8, naq eriryngvbaf vf gur 66gu obbx bs gur ovoyr, gura creuncf gur 5 qvtvg pbqr vf 66228.).  See [this webpage for a list of books in the bible.](https://www.blueletterbible.org/study/misc/66books.cfm)

Comment: @Stiv A) In my second attempt to solve it, I just used a simple strategy. Copy pasted the entire code on Google.. After 2-3 hours of research, 95% of results were on Lexicon Bible. Then I studied more about that, discovered Strong's Greek Dictionary. Used it and now I am here. B) I have never read Bible. So, I will have to do some research.

Comment: @JS1 Thank you for the guidance. I will seek upto it. rot13(Nz V nyybjrq gb cbfg guvf nafjre?) I'm asking on a positive side.

Comment: Sure you can answer what I commented although I'm not 100% sure it is correct.  I'm trying to help you solve the rest of this, as you figured out the main part, and I am not going to post any answer myself.  As for what is inside the vault, rot13(Eriryngvbaf 22:7-10 gnyxf nobhg n fpebyy, znlor gung vf vg?)

Comment: @JS1 I'm not quite experienced about Bible. Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: Since this is a VATICAN RELIC HEIST and involves rot13(gur obbx bs Eriryngvba), perhaps the vault contains an rot13(NPR RIVY NAGVPUEVFG). :-)

Comment: The body of the riddle contains the answer to the second question, you shouldn't have to speculate as it seems you guys are.

Comment: r13(Lbh unir gur pbqr pbeerpg. Juvyr lbh pbhyq bcra gur inhyg naq tb frr jung vf vafvqr, fbzrgvzrf vg'f tbbq gb unir na vqrn bs jung lbh'er ybbxvat sbe orsber lbh svaq vg. )

Comment: I did some research on the Body (catacombs of Vatican City), but nothing was relatable to it.(Revelation).b.t.w, great puzzle

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I am making a wild guess, before the real answer. rot13(Pngnpbzo Fnvagf.)